# how to filter out cell after doing QC

Tags: scrnaseq

I was wondering that the threshold that we set after doing QC in Seurat. there is an example

```
# GenePlot is typically used to visualize gene-gene relationships, but can be used for anything 
# calculated by the object, i.e. columns in object@meta.data, PC scores etc.
# Since there is a rare subset of cells with an outlier level of high mitochondrial percentage
# and also low UMI content, we filter these as well
par(mfrow = c(1, 2))
GenePlot(object = pbmc, gene1 = "nUMI", gene2 = "percent.mito")
GenePlot(object = pbmc, gene1 = "nUMI", gene2 = "nGene")`
```

[image: QC ANALYSIS]

Then its filter cell command is under:

```
# We filter out cells that have unique gene counts over 2,500 or less than 200
# Note that low.thresholds and high.thresholds are used to define a 'gate'
# -Inf and Inf should be used if you don't want a lower or upper threshold.
pbmc <- FilterCells(object = pbmc, subset.names = c("nGene", "percent.mito"), low.thresholds = c(200, -Inf), high.thresholds = c(2500, 0.05))`
```

So I want to know whether the threshold setting is depending on the picture I show?

And the below is the Geneplot I have got base on my data. How can I set my thresholds?
[image: my old geneplot]

Comment: Why have an upper bound on ngenes? Doesn't it indicate a cell is healthy if it is is able to express many genes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you end up placing filters where things become inconsistent or similar to background. In the example, which appears to be from the Seurat tutorial, there's a downward plunge in `nGenes vs. nUMI` at around 200 genes and few believable cells with more than 2000-2500 genes, so the tutorials sets filters around there. The 0.05 mitochondrial contamination is a more arbitrary round number and is less supported by the plots (one would use more like 0.06 or 0.07 if one based this solely on the plots).

Comment: Thank you@Devon Ryan If my geneplot result shows below/Users/huali/Desktop/Screen Shot 2018-08-15 at 7.35.30 PM.png.                 How should I setting my threshold ?

Comment: What do you think would be good decent values given those plots? I don't want you to just blindly follow what I say :)

Comment: I just don't know how people set their thresholds, and want to figure out how they can do to do further analysis base on their QC. So I show the data that I got. Want to find something that can be dig out.

Comment: In your case `percent.mito` should be less than 0.1 and `nGenes` should be at least 1000.

Comment: From the graphs, what would be a good upper limit cut-off for nFeatures per UMI?